# Manual order in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table of things...

```
ThingName | ThingCategory
-------------------------
thing 1   | cat1
thing 2   | cat2
thing 3   | cat3
```

How would I select them ordered by first `cat2`, then `cat1`, then `cat3`

Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to manually order the data? If so, then `ORDER BY ThingCategory = "cat2" DESC`. If you're asking for a more "general" case, then no, because there is no way to logically describe a general ordering like you're asking.

Answer (score 10):

A switch in the order clause is one way to get you there with code alone:

```
select *
from Things
order by case
    when ThingCategory = 'cat2' then 1
    when ThingCategory = 'cat1' then 2
    when ThingCategory = 'cat3' then 3
    else 4 -- Might want the default case, too
end
```

However, this type of functionality is often better handled by data rather than code. As in, if you had a `ThingCategories` table, that table could have an `Ordinal` integer column. At that point, you can simply have the following query:

```
select t.*
from Things t
    join ThingCategories c on t.ThingCategory = c.ThingCategory
order by c.Ordinal
```

This way you won't have to maintain literals in code (good luck with that), and the users can change ordering by simply updating ordinals in a table (no need to bother you).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT ThingName , ThingCategory
    FROM yourtabe
    ORDER BY 
     CASE
        WHEN ThingCategory = 'cat2' THEN 1
        WHEN ThingCategory = 'cat1' THEN 2
        WHEN ThingCategory = 'cat3' THEN 3
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely possible. Just order by a comparison:

```
ORDER BY
  ThingCategory = "cat2" DESC,
  ThingCategory = "cat1" DESC,
  ThingCategory = "cat3" DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

select thingname,thingcategory from table_name
order by field(thingcategory,'cat 2','cat 1','
cat 3');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).